# FedEx and UPS Tracking API

Tags: fedex, ups

Anyone familiar with either the FedEx or UPS APIs.  Is it possible to calculate the "guaranteed delivery date" of a package. I want to be able to tell if a package arrived late.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Tracking API and the response will contain this information formatted in XML. I think the property is 'OrderStatus', and the code for Delivered is '011'. You should download the [UPS Shipping API](http://www.ups.com/bussol?loc=en_US&viewID=productView&contentID=ct1_sol_sol_olt) and read the Track specifications and examples.

As far as the 'guaranteed delivery date', it seems to only be available for UPS Freight LTL Guaranteed (most UPS options does not guarantee) You can however **compare the** `/TrackResponse/Shipment/**ScheduledDeliveryDate**` (and Time) to the `/TrackResponse/Shipment/DeliveryDetails/**DeliveryDate**/Date`.

And, it seems to follow that if the shipment has a guaranteed date, then Scheduled date should equal the Delivery Date.